# Are there any mammals whose males can feed with milk?

Tags: zoology, mammals, sexual-dimorphism

Are there any mammals whose males can feed the offsprings with milk from the breasts?

Comment: @GriffinEvo: Birds are not mammals, meaning the question may still be valid.

Comment: See the answer to the question, it covers mammals too. @ChrisStronks

Comment: I edited the title of the linked Q so that it is clear that it also covers mammals.